# Within a while loop, how do you keep track of how many iterations a a loop as done?

Tags: java, loops, foreach, while-loop, increment

I'm trying to make this code to where the while loops only does 50 iterations of the foreach loop or until the hasAChildFoundMother is true.

I need to declare a variable that will be used to keep track of the number of iterations and that variable will be part of the condition of the while loop; also, the variable will need to be incremented inside the while loop but outside the foreach loop.

The problem I'm really having trouble with is how to increment it "inside the while loop but outside the foreach loop".

```
public void findMother() {

         Random generator = new Random();

         while (!hasAChildFoundMother()) {

             for (Turtle babyTurtles : this.babyTurtles) {
                 double degrees = generator.nextInt(90) + 1;
                 babyTurtles.turn(degrees);

                 int distance = generator.nextInt(50 - 10) + 10;
                 babyTurtles.forward(distance);
             }

        }


    }
```

Comment: Initialise before the while loop, do your test in the while condition, increment inside the while loop but outside of the for loop (i.e. stick it before the line of code with the `for` on it, but after the line of code with the `while` on it).

Comment: Try googling before coming here

Comment: Thanks. I did "google" this before coming here, but sometimes things just don't come as easy to some people. I got the jist of what I was suppose to do but I just wanted to make sure. Thanks for being a dick about it though LOL,

Comment: Did you find a suitable answer? Could you leave a comment and/or accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be an ideal case for using a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50 && !hasAChildFoundMother(); i++) {
   for (Turtle babyTurtles : this.babyTurtles) {
      ...
   }
}
```

If you *really* are not allowed to use a `for` loop for this, and it needs to be a `while` loop, you can go for this second-best:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 50 && !hasAChildFoundMother()) {
   for (Turtle babyTurtles : this.babyTurtles) {
      ...
   }
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void findMother() {

         Random generator = new Random();
         int i = 0;
         while (!hasAChildFoundMother() && i <=50) {
             //HERE
             //i++
             for (Turtle babyTurtles : this.babyTurtles) {
                 double degrees = generator.nextInt(90) + 1;
                 babyTurtles.turn(degrees);

                 int distance = generator.nextInt(50 - 10) + 10;
                 babyTurtles.forward(distance);
             }
             //OR HERE
             i++;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A little confusing of a question but I think it should just be as simple as this:

declare `count` variable and inside the while loop add `count++`. Then set a condition for count to stop at 50.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void findMother() {
     int counter = 0;
     Random generator = new Random();

     while ((!hasAChildFoundMother()) && (counter < 50)) {
         counter++;
         for (Turtle babyTurtles : this.babyTurtles) {
             double degrees = generator.nextInt(90) + 1;
             babyTurtles.turn(degrees);

             int distance = generator.nextInt(50 - 10) + 10;
             babyTurtles.forward(distance);
         }

    }


}
```

So basically you count how many times you run the while loop.  Every time you start a new loop it will check if you've done 50 iterations, and if so, will finish.

Note, important that (counter < 50) **not** (counter <= 50).  The latter will run 51 times.